# Error while trying to clean install OS X El Capitan (Apple ID auth error)

Tags: macos, install, apple-id

I am trying to do a clean install of El Capitan using guide on support.apple.com. I reformatted they drive as told, but now I am getting an error while trying to do the new install. Every time I try to log in with my Apple ID, I get the following error:

```
AMD-Action:authenticate:SP
```

I have no clue why this is happening. I am doing a reinstall of macOS Sierra on my other mac and this is going as it should. I also see the device logged into the Apple ID when checking it on appleid.apple.com.

Does anyone know how I could get out of this? I don't have any backups, so I really need to do this install.

Answer (score 1):

it's an Apple id problem.
Solution:
Power on your Mac and keep Command+Option+R (CMD+ALT+R)
Then connect your wifi network and install without Apple id.
i tested, it's work.

Comment: How do I install without using an Apple ID? It pratically forces me to log in when I go through the steps.

Comment: I would like to know that also, I have the same problem.